# How can a program know whether it's ClickOnce or not?

Tags: .net, clickonce, publish

I want to release a program for two versions, general and clickonce.

In general one, it include updating code for updating program, but clickonce one is not.

But, they are in the same solution/project code.

That is to say, I want to know how to know if a program or application can tell if it is clickonce or not itself by code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell if your app is installed via ClickOnce via the `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` property.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.isnetworkdeployed.aspx):

> If you want your application to run both inside and outside of a ClickOnce deployment (for example, if you need to debug your application on the local computer before deploying it), test IsNetworkDeployed before accessing the CurrentDeployment property.
>
> IsNetworkDeployed will return true regardless of whether the application is installed or hosted online, and regardless of whether it was installed from a Web site, file share, or CD-ROM.